# Json string convert to List for windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

```
[  
   {  
      "TotalCount":5,
      "purchaseStatus":"0",
      "inviteCount":0,
      "status":"success",
      "statusCode":"200",
      "message":"success",
      "user":[  
         {  
            "id":"ac789045e3f109f536e8c217e4e78fe6",
            "firstname":"Srinivasan",
            "lastname":"CP",
            "emailid":"seenu4689@gmail.com",
            "prof_image_path":"http:\/\/gps-dev.gpsmobitrack.com\/pickzy_dev\/upload\/img_2015-04-11-09-04-43.png",
            "gcm_regid":"NULL",
            "ios_device_id":"",
            "longitude":"80.245255",
            "latitude":"13.035394",
            "relationship":"Friend",
            "track_userid":"361",
            "date":"2015-04-18",
            "time":"13:08"
         },
         {  
            "id":"7ca84ee8cc024e3cf2f0736f89dc4ece",
            "firstname":"srini",
            "lastname":"cp",
            "emailid":"srinipickzy3@gmail.com",
            "prof_image_path":"http:\/\/gps-dev.gpsmobitrack.com\/pickzy_dev\/upload\/img_2015-04-11-08-04-41.png",
            "gcm_regid":"",
            "ios_device_id":"",
            "longitude":"80.245255",
            "latitude":"13.035394",
            "relationship":"Friend",
            "track_userid":"365",
            "date":"2015-04-21",
            "time":"19:26"
         },
         {  
            "id":"ef5b4c49b893c55ec77428b2c265510e",
            "firstname":"Naveen",
            "lastname":"Kumar",
            "emailid":"naveen.kumar@pickzy.com",
            "prof_image_path":"http:\/\/gps-dev.gpsmobitrack.com\/pickzy_dev\/upload\/img_2015-04-11-08-04-51.png",
            "gcm_regid":"NULL",
            "ios_device_id":"fbe87350c14ccbccc1ec4ad90986faa9c1124273ed9fb7708965c83a06dd7c32",
            "longitude":"80.245392",
            "latitude":"13.035848",
            "relationship":"Brother",
            "track_userid":"367",
            "date":"2015-04-10",
            "time":"17:45"
         },
         {  
            "id":"e6050d8b5d378cbc791ebab1295dd301",
            "firstname":"Parthiban",
            "lastname":"V M",
            "emailid":"parthibanemi@gmail.com",
            "prof_image_path":"http:\/\/gps-dev.gpsmobitrack.com\/pickzy_dev\/upload\/img_2015-03-28-07-03-52.png",
            "gcm_regid":"NULL",
            "ios_device_id":"",
            "longitude":"0.000000",
            "latitude":"0.000000",
            "relationship":"Friend",
            "track_userid":"368",
            "date":"2015-04-21",
            "time":"01:13"
         },
         {  
            "id":"9848d03341103f52816bf4d5a1e5467c",
            "firstname":"Naveen kumar",
            "lastname":"kumar",
            "emailid":"naveenkumar3506@gmail.com",
            "prof_image_path":"http:\/\/gps-dev.gpsmobitrack.com\/pickzy_dev\/upload\/img_2015-04-11-02-04-01.png",
            "gcm_regid":"NULL",
            "ios_device_id":"da8ef3258c4fbc42085ab1dcb62c7b6a4bd60112bb5507284a7a8b3958808c43",
            "longitude":"80.244835",
            "latitude":"13.035032",
            "relationship":"Other",
            "track_userid":"370",
            "date":"2015-04-18",
            "time":"19:38"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: You cant just copy/paste your json and wait for an answer. What have you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [Json2Csharp](http://json2csharp.com) website to convert your json string into model class.

the model classes of your Json Data will be something like this:

```
public class User
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public string emailid { get; set; }
    public string prof_image_path { get; set; }
    public string gcm_regid { get; set; }
    public string ios_device_id { get; set; }
    public string longitude { get; set; }
    public string latitude { get; set; }
    public string relationship { get; set; }
    public string track_userid { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
    public string purchaseStatus { get; set; }
    public int inviteCount { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string statusCode { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<User> user { get; set; }
}
```

after that, as @hans Olsson said use [Json.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) Nu-Get package library to deserialize json string into Model classes those you just got from Json2Csharp website.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>("") // your json data as string in the parameter.
```

Answer (score 1):

First create your data classes, you can use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to create them for you. Then use NuGet to add a reference [Json.Net](https://json.codeplex.com/).

Then you'll need something like:

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(YourJson)`

Answer (score 0):

Some directions for you research.

## 3 steps

- Get json as string
- Parse json to an object
- Bind the object to your list

## Get json as string

Put your json into a string. Do you have to download it? Look for this.

## Parse json to an object

Build an architecture of objects. What stuffs are contains in your json? You can use Visual Studio to help you our a tool like json2csharp. Now, you have to deserialize.
You can use a library like Json.NET to do the work for you. I let you look into it.

## Bind the object to your list

Just to be sure, you ask for a listbox ?